# Get name attribute from dropzone using Laravel when uplode images

Tags: laravel, dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone with Laravel  and I want to store multiple image for news . I put the paramName: to Dropzone configuration , i have tow route 
one for uplode images with action second for store new news [this image show tow route for uplode image and store news](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peJlU.png)

[this image show dropzone configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx1LV.png)